# In Django how to add user to many-to-many filed

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I like to add permission to those users who I add to a many-to-many relation.
I have a `Projekt` model where I like to add multiple users like this:

```
class Projekt(models.Model):

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.projekt)

    projekt = models.TextField(max_length=150)
    company_name = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    jogosult_01 = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, blank=True)
```

I add the users in the Django Admin page with holding down cmd then save and it shows everything is OK.

If try to get the values like this:

```
{% for u in jogosult %}
    {{ u.jogosult_01 }}
{% endfor %}
```

it say `auth.user none`.

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def projects(request):

    jogosult = Projekt.objects.filter(jogosult_01_id=request.user).order_by('-date')

     context = {
        'jogosult': jogosult,
     }

     return render(request, 'stressz/projects.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User` objects have access to their related `Projekt` objects:

```
@login_required
def projects(request):

    jogosult = request.user.projekt_set.all() #<-- HERE!

     context = {
        'jogosult': jogosult,
     }

     return render(request, 'stressz/projects.html', context)
```

Is full documented at [Many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)